# Mysql rows iserting speed

Tags: php, mysql, pixel, tracking

I have **VPS** with next configuration:

> CPU: 4 X 2.4 GHz
>
> RAM: 8GB
>
> 160 GB SSD DISK
>
> OS: CENTOS 7
>
> CPANEL
>
> 400 MB/S PORT SPEED
>
> *Server is located in Lithunia, Vilnius.*

I have created Tracking Pixel with PHP for my partner websites.

**pixel.php**

```
<?php

  $im=imagecreate(1,1);

  $white=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);

  imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);

  header("content-type:image/jpg");

  imagejpeg($im);

  imagedestroy($im);


ob_start();
require_once 'config/DB.php';


// SET COOKIE 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {

    $guestcookie = sha1(time() . rand() . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . rand());
    setcookie('uid',$guestcookie);
    $_COOKIE['uid'] = $guestcookie;

}

if(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {

    $guestcookie = $_COOKIE['uid'];

}

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO pixel1(uID, IP) VALUES(:uid, :ip)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $guestcookie);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ip", $ip);

    $stmt->execute();




?>
```

But when there is about 20,000 request to my tracking pixel in 1 minute,
`Pixel.php` only inserting about 1,500 rows in MySql Table, and after that, my server and website works badly.

Comment: Show the structure of your table, including indexes and engine. Show the cardinality of each index.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jDf2dQ
https://ibb.co/fUzjsk

Comment: are there any entries in the mysql error log?

Comment: No there nothing in error log.

Comment: May be caused by traffic? See server details, can this server works with such great data?